# How should we serve God?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, simchah-joy-happiness, yirat-shamaim

Psalm 100 says:

> עִבְד֣וּ אֶת־יְהוָ֣ה בְּשִׂמְחָ֑ה

Serve God with joy.

Psalm 2 says:

> עִבְד֣וּ אֶת־יְהוָ֣ה בְּיִרְאָ֑ה וְ֝גִ֗ילוּ בִּרְעָדָֽה

Serve God with awe/fear; tremble with fright.

How can one do both at the same time?

I suppose one *can* do both, but it's rare.  In my case, as a physicist, I always experienced quite a thrill when I saw that the most complicated things in the world derive from simple equations, simple principles.  Understanding the laws of physics and solving intricate problems always had me in awe and made me appreciate how "smart" God is.  This is what Einstein called “cosmic religious feeling”.  It has to be experienced to be understood.  The awe and the joy were indeed there at the same time.  However, (1) there was no fear, and (2) I don't see how I was "serving God".

Comment: Who ever said to do both at the same time??

Comment: It is actually possible to be fearful and joyful simultaneously. Did you ever ride a roller coaster?

Comment: Since when do we follow the advice of tehiilim?

Comment: The translation of the word גִ֗ילוּ is incorrect. A better translation is something like "be elated". Which, in a sense, supports my thinking that one can be happy and fearful simultaneously. But, @Loani makes a good point, in that, this can be metaphorical. It is certainly not a commandment nor a suggestion, necessarily.

Comment: Rabbi Avraham Eliyahu Kaplan has an essay that might answer your question, called [בעקבות היראה](http://www.aishdas.org/raek/yirah.pdf) printed in the book of the same name (see especially the first three pages). He uses the imagery of a father carrying a baby who is happy and also concerned so that the baby doesn't fall

Comment: See berachot 30b

Comment: Maurice, I believe that Ramba"m (or is it Rav Moshe Chaim Lutzatto?) has a somewhat detailed explanation on the degrees of "Yir'ah" - "fear" as it relates to one's reaction to God. One is actual "fear" of punishment for disobeying the commandments, which is why people follow the commandments. The other is this sense of "awe" and "reverence" that results in wanting to follow God's commandments, because one understands and appreciates God's magnificence and is humbled at how insignificant man is by comparison.

Comment: How should one serve electricity ? With fear, trembling at the thought of being electrocuted, or with joy, by focusing on all the scientific advancements which it engendered ?

Answer (score 1):

As a more homiletical than exegetical discourse, this question is presented in the Midrash on Tehilim ([ch. 100](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14295&st=&pgnum=548)). IMHO, the fundamental reconciliation is simply that both happiness/joy and fear [of God] should be exercised in one’s service of God.

Comment: I don’t have Braude’s translation of the Midrash at hand but if a reader does feel free to include it in the post.

Comment: Seems to me you are just restating my question.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Either you disagree with my understanding of the Midrash (since it wasn’t me who authored that Midrash) or you’re asking *not* how to reconcile the pesukim but rather for emotional-psychological guidance which, in that case, might be off-topic.

Comment: The midrash you quote says: Do both.  My question was: HOW do you do both?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi So the latter, I see. Do you really think both feelings are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Yes.  I am not a fan of the roller-coaster or chamber of horrors analogy.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the verses that suggest one interpretation over the other, i.e. whether you can act joyfully and fearfully at the same time or separately. So, you can use whichever interpretation you wish. However, another idea is we are talking about the "fear" of the awesomeness of God. Thus, e.g., when one prays, while he is thinking about God's magnificence and "trembles" at that thought, the act of praying is an expression of his joy to be able to address God and express his feelings in having that conversation with God. So, both get accomplished.

Answer (score -1):

The difficulty arises by misunderstanding the meaning of the word יראה as used in Tehillim.

יראה (Yirah) has a connotation of *action* or *movement*, like is found in Tehillim 76:9.

> מִ֭שָּׁמַיִם הִשְׁמַ֣עְתָּ דִּ֑ין אֶ֖רֶץ יָֽרְאָ֣ה וְשָׁקָֽטָה׃

From the Heavens judgement is heard, the earth quakes and is silent.

In that context, Tehillim 2:11 translates as, "Serve G-d with action, and rejoice with shaking."

That means the outer expression of your joy as discussed in Tehillim 100:2, is joviality and laughter, even to extent of shaking.

The emphasis being that it isn't enough to simply have happy thoughts, or even to be filled with happy feelings, but to share your happiness externally with those around you through your actions.

Comment: I really don't understand the basis of all these anonymous down votes to my answer. Is it that people disagree with the dictionary definition of יראה as found in Jastrow (meaning to tremble) quoting Shabbat 88a in the name of Chizkiyah which quotes the line from Tehillim 76:9 that I mention? Or that Sefer Reishit Chochma has the same understanding of the word?

Comment: Sefaria translates it as: "In heaven You pronounced sentence; the earth was numbed with fright".  I personally don't like the term "fear of God", and prefer "being in awe of God", which I believe is ine intent.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi The Hebrew משמים is not 'In Heaven". The 'Mem' prefix translates as 'from'. 'Numbed with fright' is a translation from someone who doesn't know the simple meaning of words. That simply isn't there in the Hebrew. But your question is about understanding the meaning as presented in Tehillim. That means understanding the common usage of the root as it appears in that context within Tehillim. That's asking a lot in this day and age. (sadly)

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Also, דין translates better as judgement, like I translated it. "Sentence" is actually more like גזרה (gazerah). Just to clarify, judgement is about deciding the merit of a particular case. Sentence is the consequence that follows upon the heels of a judgement. Meaning, like do you pay a fine or get sentenced to jail time.

Comment: Can you attribute a source to this explanation? Perhaps, the lack of it is what caused all the downvotes?

Comment: I downvoted because I think this is wrong. Probably others felt similarly. I didn't comment originally because I didn't think commenting would help anything, not because I'm trying to keep anything secret. There's no secret vendetta here. Just a lot of Jews expressing their honest informed opinions as productively as they can